# What is the relationship between #include <conio.h> and getch() method?

Tags: c++, multiplication

I would like to know about this.
 ***the relationship between  #include  and getch() method***

Comment: The function `getch` is declared in `conio.h`

Comment: Thanks Thomas sir. Actually sir, I wanted to know the reason for using it.

Comment: @KumarThapa But this is a totally different question from the one you have posted.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Mam, thank you for pointing out me. But, it would be very helpful to understand if you put some clarification of using it, mam.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the relationship between #include  and getch() method?

`getch()` is declared inside the header file of `conio.h`, so you need to set the preprocessor directive `#include <conio.h>` in order to you use `getch()`. Without `#include <conio.h>` you can not use `getch()`.

Note: `conio.h` is not supported by all C/C++ implementations and is not part of the C standard libraries. Rather use `getc()` or `getchar()` for catching a character from the input if you want to compile C or C++ code on Unix or Linux.

---

Your comment:

> Mam, thank you for pointing out me. But, it would be very helpful to understand if you put some clarification of using it, mam.

Beside the case, that this is not the question you have asked for, this is not how Stack Overflow works. This is not a tutorial platform; it is a platform to ask for help if you did not understand a certain topic. You need to declare what you did not understand and we can help you.

If you look for a tutorial about `getch()`, here is one:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/

By the way, I´m not a Mam, but Ok.

Comment: Note that `getc` etc standard library functions are generally not any kind of replacement for `getch`. Instead, something like *curses* library does similar things as `conio`.